# <tr> inside <td> not displaying properly - displaying contents in 2 line instead of 1 line

Tags: html, xslt

From the below piece of code `description_line_1` should be inside in the same cell of `product_description`. So, after displaying `product_description`,
`description_line_1` will display in next line. But only problem is `description_line_1` line itself coming in 2 lines instead of single line.

```
<tr style="font-size: 9px; ">
    <td style="text-align: right;"><xsl:value-of select="line_number" /></td>
    <td style=" text-align: left;" ><xsl:value-of select="product_description" />
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="description_line_1" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td style=" text-align: right;"><xsl:value-of select="product_quantity" /></td>
</tr>
```

For eg,

Expected result :

```
Product_Description

Descrition...
description line 1
```

Actual result am getting now : ( its displaying line this)

```
Product_Description

Descrition...
description line
1
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to show a sample of your input XML please? Also, as you are outputing HTML, could you show your expected and actual results as HTML and not just text? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all. I found the issue here. I have to give width to the inner table tag

```
<tr style="font-size: 9px; ">
    <td style="text-align: right;"><xsl:value-of select="line_number" /></td>
    <td style=" text-align: left;" ><xsl:value-of select="product_description" />
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="description_line_1" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td style=" text-align: right;"><xsl:value-of select="product_quantity" /></td>
</tr>
```